# Decoding pipe symbol in apex

Tags: apex, xml, developer

In a response of a callout, I am getting a XML. Sometimes, values contains encoded value of Pipe symbol as given below

```
<Name>Test &#124; Shift Happens: Test data </Name>
```

I am struggling to get the correct value. for e.g. in above case, I should get

Test | Shift Happens: Test data

I tried unescapeXml() and other encdoing utility methods but nothing works. Even, I tried replacing the `"&#124;"` with corresponding symbol but it does not work.
I am using getText() method of DOM.XMLNode class.

Comment: Can you show the code for how you are unescaping it? Just want to rule out any potential issue with how you are attempting to unescape that string.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually getting [HTML Entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) in XML. So, you should use [unescapeHtml4()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

```
String str = 'Test &#124; Shift Happens: Test data ';
String conStr = str.unescapeHtml4();
System.debug(conStr);
```

Comment: Hi @salwsforce-sas, I have a field value (external object field) having value containing pipe symbol. I tried that way in apex but, it is not getting converted. I also tried unescapeHtml3() and unescapeUnicode(). They didn't work as well. Any other solution? The error I receive is - System.QueryException: unexpected token: '&#124;'